# Terminate XMPPTCPConnection.connect attempt

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how to properly terminate a XMPPTCPConnection.connect() attempt.  I've been running into an issue when a user inputs incorrect information and is forced to wait out the Timeout of 60s.  I've tried the following but I'm assuming they fail because the connection hasnt been established yet.

```
 connection.disconnect();

 connection.instantShutdown();
```

What is the proper way to terminate a connection attempt so that you dont have to wait on the time out error

```
WARNING: shutdownDone was not marked as successful by the writer thread
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 60000ms (~60s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:253)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1269)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:494)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.instantShutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:483)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.notifyConnectionError(XMPPTCPConnection.java:863)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$2700(XMPPTCPConnection.java:139)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.writePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1419)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.access$2800(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1170)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1218)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```